# How to getopts after $1 in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, arguments, getopts

I want to run the script as `./script speed -a some_value -b some_value` also `./script accuracy -a some_value -b some_value`

What I tried is

```
while [ -n "$1" ]; do 

    case "$1" in

    speed)  

        for i in "${@:2}"
        do while getopts "a:b:" opt; do
            case "${opt}" in 
                a) list=$OPTARG
                    echo $list
                    ;;
                b) list2=$OPTARG
                    echo $list2
                    ;;
            esac
           done     
        done
        echo "speed option passed" 
        break ;;

    accuracy) echo "similar to above function"
              break ;;


    *) echo "Option $1 not recognized" ;; # In case you typed a different option other than a,b,c

    esac

    shift

done
```

getting output as when ran `./script speed -a some_value`

```
this is something
speed option passed
```

I don't know if this is possible or not or is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: Post a self-contained example.  This fails with `something: command not found`

Comment: its a snippet not full code something is a function, remove something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want the outer loop (`while [ -n "$1" ]; do`), unless you want to be able to process multiple subcommands in a single run. That is, do you want this:

```
./script speed -a some_value -b some_value accuracy -a some_value -b some_value
```

To be roughly equivalent to this:

```
./script speed -a some_value -b some_value
./script accuracy -a some_value -b some_value
```

If not, remove that loop because you'll only be processing one subcommand per run. If you do want to process more than one subcommand per run, then you need to take some extra steps to remove or skip over the arguments relating to one subcommand before running the next one.

You *do* want to remove the `for i in "${@:2}"` loop -- that just doesn't mix with the way `getopts` works. What you do need to do is skip over the subcommand name before processing the options. You could either use `shift` to remove the subcommand name, something like this:

```
case "$1" in
    speed)
        shift    # Remove the first argument ("speed")
        while getopts "a:b:" opt; do
            ...
```

If you're going to allow multiple subcommands, add `shift $((OPTIND-1))` sfter the `getopts` loop, to get it ready for the next subcommand.

Or you could modify `OPTIND` to tell `getopts` that it's already processed the first argument and it can go to work on the second:

```
case "$1" in
    speed)
        OPTIND=2    # Tell getopts to start processing at arg #2
        while getopts "a:b:" opt; do
            ...
```

If you're going to handle multiple subcommands with this method... well, it's a bit more complicated and I think I'll duck the question.

Yet another option is to put the code for each subcommand in a function, and call it with all but the first argument:

```
speed_subcommand() {
    local OPTIND
    while getopts "a:b:" opt; do
        ...
}

case "$1" in
    speed)
        speed_subcommand "${@:2}" ;;
    accuracy)
        accuracy_subcommand "${@:2}" ;;
    ...
```

This method doesn't really mix with handling multiple subcommands per run.

Comment: Thank you sir for your generous answer it is exactly what I was looking for